# how to get result of query without using result() or row() in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

I have a function in named `get_all_Emp()` model returning,

```
return $this->db->get();
```

which i am calling in controller as,

```
$items    = $this->Item->get_all_Emp();
```

but instead of returning result it returns, `CI_DB_mysqli_result Object`ie.,

```
 CI_DB_mysqli_result Object
(
    [conn_id] => mysqli Object
        (
            [affected_rows] => 24
            [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $
            [client_version] => 50011
            [connect_errno] => 0
            [connect_error] => 
            [errno] => 0
            [error] => 
            [error_list] => Array
                (
                )

            [field_count] => 44
            [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket
            [info] => 
            [insert_id] => 0
            [server_info] => 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
            [server_version] => 50722
            [stat] => Uptime: 540  Threads: 1  Questions: 1117  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 385  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 171  Queries per second avg: 2.068
            [sqlstate] => 00000
            [protocol_version] => 10
            [thread_id] => 36
            [warning_count] => 0
        )

    [result_id] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 44
            [lengths] => 
            [num_rows] => 24
            [type] => 0
        )

    [result_array] => Array
        (
        )

    [result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [custom_result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [current_row] => 0
    [num_rows] => 24
    [row_data] => 
)
```

but if i use ,

```
$query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
```

instead of `return get_all_Emp()` I get the appropriate result.
so is there any way of doing it using former method and still get the answer
Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: use `$items    = $this->Item->get_all_Emp()->result();` in your controller

Comment: then i get "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: because it isn't an array. its an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused between an array and an object. There is plenty of information regarding this via a simple google search but essentially it boils down to:

If you have a column called `name` with an array you do something like `$row['name']` and with an object you do `$row->name` the notation is just a bit different and its more of a matter of style than anything. I prefer using an object but if I have to do manipulations arrays can be more useful.

Further `get()` doesn't actually return a result object.

1. `$this->db->get()->result()` returns an object for all rows within your params
2. `$this->db->get()->row()` returns an object for a single row
3. `$this->db->get()->result_array()` returns an array for all rows within your params
4. `$this->db->get()->row_array()` returns an array for a single row

So in your function, if you want to use an array do `return $this->db-get()->result_array();` assuming you already set a from condition.

Answer (score 1):

For array results you can use result_array(). Just return this in you model:

```
return $this->db->get("table_name")->result_array();
```

After you get something like this

```
Array(
    [0] => Array('col1' => 'somedata', 'col2' => 'somedata2'),
    [1] => Array('col1' => 'somedata', 'col2' => 'somedata2'),
)
```

Documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)